# Multiple filter result with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, filter

I'm currently using Laravel with AJAX call to database to retrieve the contents in database. Previously I'm doing languages selector that will filter the video's language. But now I intend to change it to multiple language selector. I google for multiple result filtering but none of them works for me. I'm using AJAX call when user select one language. For current case, we have multiple AJAX call with multiple select options.

**Javascript AJAX** (When you select a new language)

```
var language = $(this).text();
var channel = "{{ $channel }}";

$.ajax({
            url:'/directory/updateLanguage/live/'+language+'/'+channel,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#live').html(data);
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            url:'/directory/updateLanguage/past/'+language+'/'+channel,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#past').html(data);
            }
        });
```

URL will be execute method below from Controller:

```
public function updateLanguage($type,$language,$channel)
{
$categoryId = Channel::where('name','=',strtolower($channel))->pluck('category_id');

    if ($language == "All Languages" && $categoryId == 0)
    {
        var_dump("IF All languages and category all");
        $past = Videos::orderBy('created_at','desc')->where('active','=',1);
        $live = Videos::where('stream_active','=','1')->where('active','=',1)->orderBy('created_at','desc');    
    }else if ($categoryId != 0) {
        var_dump("Any languages and Not in 'all' ");
        $past = Videos::where('category_id','=', $categoryId)->where('stream_active','=','0')->where('active','=',1)->where('language','=',$language)->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
        $live = Videos::where('category_id','=', $categoryId)->where('stream_active','=','1')->where('active','=',1)->where('language','=',$language)->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    }else {
        var_dump("ELSE");
    }
...
}
```

I'm currently want to filter more than one languages videos. I have a video list div, I only know how to filter one language video but not multiple languages selector in database.

Comment: can you explain what you needs?

Comment: @Musthaan I want to filter more than one languages of my database video so that the video list will shows more than one languages videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the langage variable like : fr.en.nl

Then, in your PHP, you split the string like

```
$str = 'fr.en.nl';
$langages= preg_split('.', $str);
```

Finally, set the SQL request with a ORWHERE ([Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres))

```
->where('language','=',$languages[0])->orWhere('language','=',$language[1])
```

Comment: What if $str = 'fr' only, the $language[1] will be "Undefined Offset error"

Comment: Well, this is OBVISOUSLY an example. Just say `if(count(langages) > 1)` => You have to do a simple [foreach](https://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php) on your langages variable. For each value, you add a condition!